# Define a RESTful URL for a multiple insert for non-resource-specified resources?

Tags: api, rest

For example, we have `Users` and `Products` and each user can request a coupon of each product. This flag is stored like:

```
Users_Products
{"user_id": 1, "product_id": 1, "is_coupon_requested": true,  "requested_at": "2016-04-01"},
{"user_id": 1, "product_id": 2, "is_coupon_requested": false, "requested_at": "2016-04-21"},
{"user_id": 2, "product_id": 1, "is_coupon_requested": true,  "requested_at": "2016-06-01"},
:
```

And at some point an admin user wants to distribute an actual coupon code to users by specifying an id of product and a number `X` of coupons so that users who has top `X` earliest `requested_at` can obtain a coupon code.

So I want to insert following data, by kind of bulk insert operation.

```
Users_Coupons
{"user_id": 1, "product_id": 1, "coupon_code": "ABXXYZ", "is_redeemed": false},
:
```

In this case, first I tried applying RESTful URL like
`POST /users/products/:product_id/coupons`
But this skips a resource identifier of `users`. I'm not sure if it's common to do this.

Of course I can let a client call first
`GET /users?product_id={product_id}&is_coupon_requested=true&sort=is_requested_at&limit=X`
and then retrieve all user_ids and make a POST request after that.
But if possible I want to achieve this only one single API call since the server also knows to whom a coupon should be distributed and the condition would likely not changed.

I also saw Facebook and Google's `Batch` operation approach,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests
This achieves what I want to do, but I feel it over-killing for a tiny system that doesn't offer so many APIs.

Or is it better to just `POST /products/:product_id/coupons` because I cannot specify `user_id`?
I want to know the common or best practice for such needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
Request: PUT /products/:productId/coupons
Body:
{
 numberOfCoupons: 2
}
```

And then let the server do the bulk insert with the provided :productId and numberOfCoupons. The choice of PUT vs POST depends on how you want to treat multiple calls to this resource. That is, whether or not it is [idempotent](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html)

> Or is it better to just POST /products/:product_id/coupons because I
>   cannot specify user_id?

There's nothing stopping you from specifying the user_id if you want:

```
POST /products/:productId/users/:userId
```

Though I think the latter isn't really what you were after, since you just wanted to assign a number of x coupons based on a product y.

Comment: I see, so it's valid to omit /users path when an operation doesn't specify users' id. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure thing. As long as the path uniquely identifies a resource, then you can omit things from it. Let's say you want to get product with id 1. It makes more sense to GET /products/1 rather than GET /users/products/1. There's nothing stopping you from using the latter, but it's confusing and less readable.